# PHPMailer not working correctly

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a form that looks like this

```
<form action="send_attach_pear.php" type="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></p>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

that sends information to the PHP file...

```
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('zacharycook2014@utexas.edu', 'Zach Cook');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer mail() test';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$msg = "This is a message from " . $name . ".";             
$mail->Body = $msg;
```

But for some reason "$name" is not showing up in the end email.

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: add `die(var_dump($name));` after `$name = $_POST['name'];` and tell us what is the result

Comment: Are you sure that you are posting to the right page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `method` = `POST` not `type`= `POST`

Here is the code:

```
<form action="send_attach_pear.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: @casper Worth A Shot..:)

Comment: If that fixed it and if you found it useful then you can always accept the answer  as well..:)

Comment: oh... woops @Joke_Sense10